# Double Nested UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How do I make a double nested `UITableView`?

I would like to learn to make an iPhone app that has a tableview that when you click on an element takes you to another tableview which has items that can be seen in a detailed view.

I understand how to create the second layer that has items, but I am confused on how to send a user from one tableview to another by clicking on the element.

Thanks

Comment: there is a delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for UITableViewDelegate. Implement that and write code to push/present new view controller.

Comment: You better think in managing different datasources, than different UITableView, a single UITableView can be toggled to show different lists with the use of different datasources.

Comment: please Follow this link http://code4app.net/ios/RATreeView/524e2f896803fa6e31000001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below method :-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So, in above method you could programmatically make a call to another tableViewController as below:-

```
TableViewController *tableView = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:tableView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So your next table view will be presented as you wanted and also back will be provided if you have navigation bar else you will have to provide a back programmatically.

Comment: How does the "SubTableViewController" know which element in the MasterViewController called it? thanks

Comment: Exactly how many tableviewcontroller you have... Okay so in masterTable you click a row den subTable open's and you do your stuff. Then u provide a back button so as to come from subTable to masterTable. Then again same scenario. So in-short two tableview controller only required unless you moving from subtable to another subTable

Answer (score 0):

UITableView delegate method would serve this purpose.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method will capture your click event, then you can move to other view controller/Table View.